# Add values from different dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
df1:
            A    B
0  2002-01-13  3.9
1  2002-01-13  1.9
2  2002-01-14  8.0
3  2002-01-14  9.0
```

I want to create a new column `df1["C"]` with means of `B` values, per each `A` group.

Output should be:

```
            A    B     C
0  2002-01-13  3.9   2.9
1  2002-01-13  1.9   2.9
2  2002-01-14  8.0   8.5
3  2002-01-14  9.0   8.5
```

And now I want to assign `C` values to each `A` group, to another `df2`.

```
df2:
            A        D
0  2002-01-13   Joseph
1  2002-01-13     Emma
2  2002-01-13  Michael
3  2002-01-14     Anna
4  2002-01-14   Yvonne
5  2002-01-14  Anthony
```

Output should be:

```
            A        D     E
0  2002-01-13   Joseph   2.9
1  2002-01-13     Emma   2.9
2  2002-01-13  Michael   2.9
3  2002-01-14     Anna   8.5
4  2002-01-14   Yvonne   8.5
5  2002-01-14  Anthony   8.5
```

I´ve tried:

```
df1["C"] = df1.groupby("A")["B"].mean()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to add a column to df1, you can directly map the values from the groupby df1 to df2.

```
df2['E'] = df2['A'].map(df1.groupby('A').B.mean())


    A           D       E
0   2002-01-13  Joseph  2.9
1   2002-01-13  Emma    2.9
2   2002-01-13  Michael 2.9
3   2002-01-14  Anna    8.5
4   2002-01-14  Yvonne  8.5
5   2002-01-14  Anthony 8.5
```

Comment: I'd use `assign` but this is my answer.

Comment: @piRSquared, need to start using assign :)

Answer (score 2):

First question `transform`

```
df1['C'] = df1.groupby('A').B.transform('mean')
```

Second using `map` (Notice I am using the df1 directly cause I adding `drop_duplicates` )

```
df2['E']=df2.A.map(df1.drop_duplicates('A').set_index('A').C)
```

Comment: I think df2.A.map(df1.set_index('A')['C'].to_dict()) would be more clean, You don't need drop_duplicates as dictionary will take care of it. +1

Comment: @Vaishali that is true：-）

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1**

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('mean')
```

The reason your code does not work is your `groupby` object returns a series indexed by `A`.

**Parts 1 & 2**

You could perform your transformations by mapping `A` to a precalculated `groupby` object in each dataframe.

```
s = df1.groupby('A')['B'].mean()

df['C'] = df['A'].map(s)
df2['E'] = df2['A'].map(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
df['C'] = df['A'].replace(df.groupby('A')['B'].mean().to_dict())
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as [@Vaishali's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49636335/2336654) answer but uses `replace` instead.  I'd argue that you'd want to use `map` instead.

Comment: Three other answers are posted while I was drafting my answer :). I agree that either `transform` or `map` is better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

*Posting since others did not mention using `pd.merge` or `DataFrame.join`.*

If only the final output is required:

```
pd.merge(df2, df1.groupby('A', as_index=False).B.agg('mean').rename(columns={'B':'E'}), on='A')
#outputs:
            A        D     E
0  2002-01-13   Joseph   2.9
1  2002-01-13     Emma   2.9
2  2002-01-13  Michael   2.9
3  2002-01-14     Anna   8.5
4  2002-01-14   Yvonne   8.5
5  2002-01-14  Anthony   8.5
```

I have a hunch that the join based solution will be faster than the map based solutions given large data frames.